# Storage setting not loading. What do do?

Tags: storage, motorola

When looking on the storage option it just loads forever, and can't view the setting option. What do I do?

I have a Moto E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What works for me is first going to Settings >  Apps & notifications, and clearing the cache for as many apps as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem. Just put your 'Sleep' functionality to 'After 10 minutes of inactivity' and then open storage.

It will take approx 6 to 7 minutes to open. Once opened it will work fine.

With Regards,
Asif